# Configure Mic and USB speaker Jessie

Tags: usb, audio, raspbian-jessie

I would like to use the mic and usb speaker with Pi2 Jessie. Here is the output from `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0d8c:013c C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM108 Audio Controller
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1130:1620 Tenx Technology, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Can someone please let me know what needs to be done?
The speaker/mic information are as follows:
[Speaker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000ZH98LU) 
[Mic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N1YDVAS)

I have tried making the necessary modifications
1. Removed the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
2. Modified the `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf`
3. `aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: AUDIO [USB  AUDIO], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`

Did not help.

Adding the output from `/proc/asound/cards`

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [AUDIO          ]: USB-Audio - USB  AUDIO
                      USB  AUDIO at usb-3f980000.usb-1.4, full speed
 1 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835 - bcm2835 ALSA
                      bcm2835 ALSA
 2 [Device         ]: USB-Audio - USB PnP Sound Device
                      C-Media Electronics Inc. USB PnP Sound Device at usb-3f980000.usb-1.5, full spe
```